# How do I determine the route of my view?

Tags: 8

I made a new view page and I want it to be in the router table so that I can know its route, but it's not there.  How can I determine the route of this view or insert it into the router table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out what the route was for a view, I actually ended up doing this in a custom module, and then looking at the page route in the object.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function my_module_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  dpm(\Drupal::request());
}
```